# Uniqueness of the complementary subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

For two complementary subspaces $X$ and $Y$ of $V$ we have $X\oplus Y=V$. If we suppose there is another subspace $Z$ complementary to $X$ then $X\oplus Z=V$ holds. We claim that $Y$ and $Z$ are identical, i.e. $Y$ is the unique subspace complementary to $X$.

I didn't find proof for that so I tried my self. My prove goes as follows:

1. $X\oplus Y=V \Longrightarrow \textbf x+\textbf y=\textbf v$ for unique vectors $\textbf x$, $\textbf y$ and $\textbf v$, i.e. $\textbf v$ is uniquely defined as a sum of an element from $X$ and element from $Y$.
2. $X\oplus Z=V \Longrightarrow \textbf x+\textbf z=\textbf v$ for unique vectors $\textbf x$, $\textbf z$ and $\textbf v$, analogously to 1).

From these two points follows that $\textbf y=\textbf v-\textbf x=\textbf z$, so $Y\subseteq Z$.
On the other hand we have $\textbf z=\textbf v-\textbf x=\textbf y$, so $Z\subseteq Y$. Thus finally $Y=Z$.

Comment: Your proof is not correct. $x$ in 1 and 2 may not be the same.

Comment: The statement is false, for example $<(1,0)>$ and $<(0,1)>$ are complementary in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but  $<(1,0)>$ and $<(1,1)>$ too

Comment: You are trying to prove a false statement: complements are not unique. Anyway: what is your question?

Comment: Oh thank you for that. I tried to prove something else and if this was true then it would have been easier. I have to find another way.

Comment: @Crostul I have the following problem: if $X$ is complementary to $Y$ and $M$ is complementary to $N$ and if it appears that $X=M$ does it follows $Y=N$? Obviously not!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Complements of a  given subspace are far from unique.  The easiest way to see what's going on is to look at the vector space $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Each line $W$ passing through the origin is a vector subspace $\mathbb{R}^2$.  Any line passing through the origin which is not parallel to $W$ is a complementary subspace of $W$.

Comment: Sir can you provide example in case when $V$ is an infinite dimensional Vector space.

Comment: The same thing works, let $v_1, v_2, ...$ be a countable basis for for $V$, let $W$ be the span of $v_1$.  Then $$W_1 = \mathbb Rv_2 + \mathbb R v_3 + \cdots$$ and $$W_2 = \mathbb R(v_1 - v_2) + \mathbb R v_3 + \mathbb R v_4 + \cdots$$ are both complements to $W$.